# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.MouseState.X.get'?

Tags: c#, xna, compiler-errors, cursor, xna-4.0

So, I want to draw a texture in front of my cursor. here's my code:

```
private void DrawCursor()
{
    //Draws cursor
    Vector2 Mouseplace = new Vector2(MouseState.X, MouseState.Y);
    spriteBatch.Draw(cursor, Mouseplace, Color.White );
}
```

And I get this error:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.MouseState.X.get'
>   And this:
>
> Error 2   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.MouseState.Y.get'
>   How to fix those?

(Sorry if this is a noob question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseState` isn't a static class.. you'll need to do this:

```
var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Vector2 Mouseplace = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
```

etc. X and Y are public properties of a `MouseState` *instance*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`MouseState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) is not a [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) at all.

You need to create an instance of it to use [`X`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) and [`Y`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.y%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) properties..